# When is the product of all Galois conjugates of an element of a field contained in a subextension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E/K$ be a finite Galois extension with cyclic abelian Galois group. Let $L/K$ be the unique subextension such that $[E:L]$ is coprime to $p$ and $[L:K]$ is a $p$-power. Let $\tau$ be a generator of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$. Then there exists a lift $\tilde\tau\in \mathrm{Gal}(E/K)$ of $\tau$ such that $\tilde \tau$ has the same order as $\tau$ (that is, $[L:K]$).

Let $x\in E$, and assume that $\prod_{i=0}^{[L:K]-1}\tilde\tau^i(x)\in L$. Does it follow that $x\in L$?

Comment: This is maybe related to the norm? I can't really remember

Comment: No, try $p\nmid [E:K], L=K$ and $E=K(x)$.

Comment: This is not a counterexample: if $L=K$ then $\tau=1$ and $\tilde \tau=1$, and so the assumption becomes $\prod_{i=0}^0 1(x)=x\in L$, so the statement is trivially satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $p > 2$,  $K = \mathbf{Q}$, and $E = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})$. Let $x = \zeta_p$. Then $x$ lies in the fixed field of $\tilde{\tau}$, so

$$\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} \tilde{\tau}^i x = \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} \zeta_p = 1,$$

but $\zeta_p \notin L$.